# Calculating the distance between plane and origin when the point on plane and normal vector are given.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have an plane given as some "random" point on that plane and the normal vector (for that plane).

I would like to calculate the distance between the plane and the origin `(0, 0, 0)`.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

If $\,\vec p$ is the point and $\,\vec n$ is the plane's unit normal your answer is:
$$|\vec p.\vec n|$$